# Joining points in $xy-$plane

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, interpolation, fixed-points, lagrange-interpolation

Is it possible to find the equation of the curve, $y=f(x)$, that passes through the points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),(x_3,y_3),\dots$ , and$(x_n,y_n)$ so that for any $j \in [1,n)$, the length of the curve between $(x_j,y_j)$ and $(x_{j+1},y_{j+1})$ is as small as possible?

That is; the curve is almost a line between $(x_j,y_j)$ and $(x_{j+1},y_{j+1})$. In other words, we need $f(x)$ such that $f'(x_j<x<x_{j+1})=c$, where $c$ is a constant.

What I know is only joining the points, (using Lagrange's polynomial method), but that does not satisfy the condition that we require (to minimise the length of the curve).

I believe it is possible using infinite series as Fourier series or other, but I am not sure.

Any help would be really appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: *“the curve is almost a line”* – why “almost”? The shortest connection between two points  *is* a line.

Comment: If you really want the distances to be minimum, why don't you go for piecewise linear functions? A piecewise linear function would guarantee that the successive distances are as minimum as possible. If you want the function to be continuous and also differentiable, you can choose cubic splines.